Getting list of assignments a student submitted in Moodle Web Services
I am building a utility which uses Moodle (4.0) web services. So far, it is working just fine (I can get a list of participants, etc.).
I am trying to get a list of assignments that a user submitted to. Or, alternatively, trying to get all assignments for one user, along with that user's submission status.
Is this possible?
I am sure I can get a list of assignments for a course and then loop through that list, checking each one for that user's submission status but it's a lot of calls. I am hoping there is one (or two) calls I can make to keep this somewhat efficient.
Is there a way to get a list of assignments that a student submitted to?
